# Join query for any type mapping on Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I've Implemented Any relationship Tag entity mapping with Asset,Patient,Staff

I tried below JPQL Query

`em.createQuery("select t from Tag t join t.tagAssociation ta");`

I got the following error

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: An AnyType attribute cannot be join fetched error

What is wrong with the query ? 
How to write join query and I want to fetch Asset and Tag associated list.

Code:

```
 public interface ITagAssociatable {
 public String getName();   
}

 @Entity
 public class Tag {
 @Id
 private String tagSerialNumber;    

@JsonIgnore
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "tag_association_type"))
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = Asset.class, value = "Asset"),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = Staff .class, value = "Staff"),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = Patient.class, value = "Patient") })
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "tag_association_id")
private ITagAssociatable tagAssociation;
 }

    @Entity
    public class Asset implements ITagAssociatable {
@Id
private Long id;
private String name
  }

    @Entity
    public class Staff implements ITagAssociatable {
@Id
private Long id;
private String name;
  }

    @Entity
    public class Patient implements ITagAssociatable{
@Id
private Long id;
private String name
  }
```

Comment: What happens, if you type: `em.createQuery("select t from Tag t join t.tagAssociation ta", Tag.class);`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find where it is specifically forbidden (so perhaps someone else can provide a better answer?), but the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-any) warns that it is impossible to create foreign keys for this type of relation and an eager join would be quite complex. Most likely Hibernate doesn't support `join fetch` for `@Any` and will read the relations with separate selects later instead. If so you can use `@BatchSize` to read many relations with one select, avoiding the N+1 problem.

Comment: It's still the case the query is not possible? I was checking if there are any other solutions like subqueries or HQL constructor. Some good hints about that? Additional query even if mitigated with @BatchSize are not good in my situation. Thanks

Comment: Well, the warning remains in the latest version (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) so I would assume so. I guess you could resort to a native SQL query if you really must do it with a single select.